How to become Emperor of the Galaxy
I've been trying to achieve With Thunderous Applause (Become the Galactic Emperor) for quite some time. I've achieved dominance in the Galactic Community where I can pretty much guarantee any resolution passes.
I have:

Changed Council Size to 1 (me)
Added Denouncement Power
Added Veto Power
Given myself Constitutional Immunity
Been nominated Custodian
Removed term limit on custodianship

I can't figure out which steps to take next towards becoming Emperor.

Create 20 children using magic and science. Wait, you're not talking about Wh40k?

Trying to become God Emperor of Arrakis, I see? Wait, no, wrong universe.

I'd convince the Senate to grant me emergency powers—a certain amphibious representative of Naboo comes to mind as particularly gullible. Oh wait, you're not Sheev!

Looks like all that's left is for you to Proclaim the Galactic Imperium, which should be one of the available Custodian Reforms. However, if a War in Heaven is already occurring, it is too late to become the Galactic Emperor: the Awakened Empires that have gone to war with each other have upended galactic politics too badly for someone else to try to claim imperium. You'll have to get the War in Heaven to end first. Denouncing one or both Awakened Empires (a Galactic Focus) will help.
Source: https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Galactic_community#The_Custodian

Yes, this was it. I missed the drop down that had this in it when I was looking. Thank you.


Be on the galactic council first
Elect yourself as custodian of the galaxy
Remove your term limit (so your term never expires)
You can proclaim the galactic imperium (you will likely need quite a lot of favours for that)

Taken from TrueAchievements
